# -fpic not working on assembly files

Tags: file, assembly, fpic

I have built a shared library using android.mk file which has
LOCAL_CFLAGS :-  -fPIC

And built using ndk-build r10e version.

The assembly files contains arm11 assembly.

When I checked with eu-findtextrel utility it still shows relocated text.

Is there any way to enforce fPIC on assembly files?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When coding assembly, it's your job to write PIC ;)

Comment: are you using a C compiler to assemble? why not use the assembler to assemble, less confusing experience.